# Cannot catch Chrome window.location.href in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Cannot catch Chrome window.location.href in Chrome even the location not changed

```
try {
     window.location.href = 'file://folder/whatever/';
} catch (err) {
     alert("Error hit!");
}
```

Comment: I just want to point out that mixing `"` and `'` for strings is going to cause you pains one day, I suggest you stick to `'`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that chrome does not throw exception when the protocol is *file*.
But if you really want to throw exception:

```
var redirect=function(url){if (/^file/.test(url)){throw 'some exception'} window.location.href=url}

try{
   redirect('file://some/path');
} catch(e){
  alert(e);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, can you throw in an example usage for OP please?

Comment: Do you mean example like above?

Answer (score 0):

Try with three forward slashes at `file:` protocol

```
try {
     // `file://` : protocol, `/folder` : top level directory
     // `/whatever/` : folder
     window.location.href = "file:///folder/whatever/";
} catch (err) {
     alert("Error hit!");
}
```

Comment: Google chrome -- windows 8.1 -- I try wrong URL and not supported protocol ,, but can't catch it ,,

Comment: Does windows use `\\` backwards slashes? Been some time since used. What does properties of file name provide for full path to file?

Comment: What do you mean "can't catch it"? How you aware of the errors?

Comment: I just want to try if custom protocol supported or not ,,, so I set on the URL ex : "mailto:"  ,, so if the page not open alert the user ,,,,

Comment: _"I just want to try if custom protocol supported or not ,,, so I set on the URL ex : "mailto:" ,, so if the page not open alert the user ,,,, "_ You should include this description in your answer. You can also define custom protocol handlers at `navigator`

Comment: Again, have not tried windows in some time, though you should also be able to use `window.onerror` ?

Comment: I try "window.onerror"  but also if the URL not open ,,, it didn't fire ,,,

Comment: @DaniaAlBorene It is probably not an error. Custom protocols can be defined and used within the browser, see [Web-based protocol handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers) . You could try is use `setTimeout()` to check if `location.href` is different after setting `location.href` . If `setTimeout` is called browser has not navigated to different locatrrion.